# How to put consecutive numbers into table for SQL not one by one

Tags: sql

Using below codes makes a table with one column as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

```
CREATE TABLE abc (a VARCHAR(8));
INSERT INTO abc VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)
```

But how we can use a method with using (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7) , I mean something like 1:7 only?

Comment: Why are you storing an integer in a string column?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain your question a little more clearly.  ie  a) You are using (1),(2) etc, and b) what do you mean 1:7?

Comment: Why MySQL @Fresh? This is valid SQL Server (for instance) syntax as well...

Comment: @Ben I'll put $5 on MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Did anyone say [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19369557/570191)??

```
with rec as (
    select 1 i
    union all
    select i+1 from rec where i < 7
)
select * from rec
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are looking for a way to insert set of INT values in column in single batch. for example "insert 100 Identities in columnA."
there is no predefined SQL SERVER function for that. but you can work around using any system table that you sure will have sufficient number rows you are looking for.

```
    SELECT rownum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT name,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rownum
        FROM sysobjects so
    )q
    WHERE rownum <= 7
```